# Save Word files with embedded images to a single HTML page

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

I am using win32com to save DOCX to HTML:

```
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
wordFilePath = "c:\\test.docx"
doc = word.Documents.Open(wordFilePath)
txt_path = wordFilePath.split('.')[0] + '.html'
doc.SaveAs(txt_path, 10)
doc.Close()
```

However, when the DOCX has an image inside the HTML is created with the images in a subfolder.
Is there a way to convert to HTML with the images embedded?